# Why is bool 4 bytes in Marshal.SizeOf while char is only 1?

Tags: c#, data-structures

Why does **char** take 1 byte in `Marshal.SizeOf` while **bool** takes 4 bytes. Doesn't **char** has more states than a **bool**

```
char c = '\x0011';
bool b = true;
Console.WriteLine("char: " + Marshal.SizeOf(c).ToString() + "\n" 
                + "bool: " + Marshal.SizeOf(b).ToString());

//char: 1
//bool: 4
```

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Set](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Char is 2 bytes, not 1; yes, char is atomic

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch **everything** is a sequence of bytes at the underlying level. If you mean more directly, then no: each char is 2 bytes

Comment: boolean's are padded to 4 bytes? ... really?

Comment: @MarcGravell I get a size of 1 byte, not 2 bytes.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead bool has size of 4 bytes see edited question

Comment: So your question is actually about Marshal.SizeOf - that changes things. Note that if you used the normal `sizeof` operator, you'd have gotten 2 for char and 1 for bool. That does not include the (variable) padding that could happen if they were in a class/struct.

Comment: Basically, everything @harold said. `Marshal` only relates to interop scenarios, passing data in/out of .NET. It doesn't tell you the size of things when they are inside .NET

Comment: Do you actually have a problem where this is relevant? If it is not Interop you usually do not care except if you have many class objects with padded bools and you try to reduce memory consumption. There are other ways to solve that problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at what the Marshal class makes of it. Try this to see what the compiler thinks:

```
 Console.WriteLine("char: " + sizeof(char).ToString() + "\n"
                 + "bool: " + sizeof(bool).ToString());
```

> char : 2
>   bool : 1

Applying `Marshal.SizeOf()` to local variables isn't the intended use. The basic idea is that you create a `struct` for interop and then the concept of padding becomes relevant.

Comment: I'm really confused now. Why char would need 2 bytes? Because of unicode?

Comment: Yes. 1-byte chars went out of fashion years ago. .NET chars and strings use Unicode throughout.

Comment: thanks, and would appreciate if you can explain why a struct would apply padding? Or does a struct just create a 4-byte pointer?

Comment: `struct`s often have to match unmanaged datastructures. There are attributes to control the layout of a .NET struct.